# Row wrapping when a column resize (Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

folks!

I am experiencing a problem. I hope you can help me.

I have three columns and two rows on Bootstrap:

```
 _ _ _
|_|_|_| -> 1,2,3
|_|_|_| -> 4,5,6
```

When the 2nd cell increases its size, this happens:

```
 _ _ _ 
|_| |_| -> 1,2,3
 _|_|_| -> -,2,4
|_|_|   -> 5,6,-
```

Is there any way to increase the height of the whole row to adjust its size to the tallest 'div', like:

```
 _ _ _
| | | | -> 1,2,3
|_|_|_| -> 1,2,3
|_|_|_| -> 4,5,6
```

Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1:**

Well-Made, I tried this, but the result was everything at the same line. :(

To not to change the global row settings, I applied your solution to a new class instead called `row-products`. Here are my codes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row row-products">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="product rounded">
            <img src="../img/portfolio/item1.jpg" class="img-responsive rounded" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                <h4>Item 1</h4>
                <h3>US$ 120</h3>
                <p class="text-muted">small description</p>
            </div>
            <div id="item1">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#item1" href="#item1_clp">Details</a>
                <div id="item1_clp" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
                    <div class="panel-body">big description </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="product rounded">
            <img src="../img/portfolio/item2.jpg" class="img-responsive rounded" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                <h4>Item 2</h4>
                <h3>US$ 120</h3>
                <p class="text-muted">small description</p>
            </div>
            <div id="item2">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#item2" href="#item2_clp">Details</a>
                <div id="item2_clp" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
                    <div class="panel-body">big description </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="product rounded">
            <img src="../img/portfolio/item1.jpg" class="img-responsive rounded" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                <h4>Item 3</h4>
                <h3>US$ 120</h3>
                <p class="text-muted">small description</p>
            </div>
            <div id="item3">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#item3" href="#item3_clp">Details</a>
                <div id="item3_clp" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
                    <div class="panel-body">big description </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="product rounded">
            <img src="../img/portfolio/item2.jpg" class="img-responsive rounded" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                <h4>Item 4</h4>
                <h3>US$ 120</h3>
                <p class="text-muted">small description</p>
            </div>
            <div id="item2">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#item4" href="#item4_clp">Details</a>
                <div id="item4_clp" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
                    <div class="panel-body">big description </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="product rounded">
            <img src="../img/portfolio/item1.jpg" class="img-responsive rounded" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                <h4>Item 5</h4>
                <h3>US$ 120</h3>
                <p class="text-muted">small description</p>
            </div>
            <div id="item5">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#item5" href="#item5_clp">Details</a>
                <div id="item5_clp" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
                    <div class="panel-body">big description </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
        <div class="product rounded">
            <img src="../img/portfolio/item2.jpg" class="img-responsive rounded" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio-caption">
                <h4>Item 6</h4>
                <h3>US$ 120</h3>
                <p class="text-muted">small description</p>
            </div>
            <div id="item6">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#item6" href="#item6_clp">Details</a>
                <div id="item6_clp" class="panel-collapse collapse out">
                    <div class="panel-body">big description </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-products {
  padding: 25px;
  /*padding-top: 30px;*/
  display: flex;
}

.row-products > div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: i think you can use table...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Vishnu, I don't think so, because the list of items is intended to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 rows like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

that shouldn't be a problem.

But if you have a single row with 6 col's in there like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

I would suggest using `flexbox`.

CSS would look something like this:

```
.row {
   display: flex;
}

.row > div {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Ofcourse depending on the col-* class you should only do this on certain media queries otherwise the col's wouldn't stack under each other when the condition is met.

Comment: Yeah, since I opted for Bootstrap grid system, I think it's better to encapsulate all the row contents at the same row item, so Bootstrap or Flex will decide where to wrap based on the screen size. If I do 

`
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
`

it'd be hard to make this work in a small screen.

Comment: Yes in that case, I would suggest the flexbox way. Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks